# Combining .net Regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to merge two .net regular expressions into one. The following expressions are validating excel like cell names.

```
Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[A-Za-z]{1}[\w\.]*$") && 
    !Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[A-Za-z]{1,2}\d+$");
```

The first part ensures the cell name starts with a character and can be any length. The second ensures the cell name is not a cell reference; for example, A1, AA1, AA11, etc.

Comment: `[\w.]*` matches runs of characters that may be dots, letters, underscores, *or digits*. Please provide examples of what you do want to match.

Comment: Side note: Excel cell names may have up to three characters at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work:

```
^[A-Za-z](?![A-Za-z]?\d+$)[\w.]*$
```

Since the first regex must match and the second must not, I moved parts of the second one into a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which doesn't consume any characters in the match but still would enable the RE to reject strings that would have matched the second RE.

Comment: Thanks Johannes, this solution got me most of the way.  However, AA11Test is a valid "named cell" and this RE fails.   

This seems to catch all instances:  
^[A-Za-z](?![A-Za-z]{0,2}\d+$)[\w.]*$

Comment: Eek, yes, forgot an anchor. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can eliminate the 2nd call to `IsMatch` and it shouldn't make a difference.

```
Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[A-Za-z]{1}[\w.]*$")
```

This pattern in itsslef insures that no digits (0 - 9) are present in the string, so it should be sufficient.

Comment: The second RE must not match, though, so it's not a simple matter of folding both REs into one.

Comment: @Johannes: If the first matches, the second *cannot* match.

Comment: `\w` includes `0-9`. In fact, `"AA1"` is already a simple counter-example, given by the OP.